# Bought "imported" Xbox Series S, unable to purchase Game Pass

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, xbox-game-pass

To get Game Pass, console shows 1$ first month, later 9.90$. But in India its price should be 50₹, later 499₹. I'm not comfortable with dollars transaction.

1. Can you please guide me how to get Game Pass for imported Xbox Series S?
2. Is there any community site where I can post Xbox related questions?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Your question is ok, but the second part where you ask for site recommendation is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is update the region on your Console and Account to have prices and such localized to your desired region:

Microsoft Account info via website:

1. [Sign in](https://account.microsoft.com/profile) to your Microsoft Account Online
2. Select Edit Profile Info
3. Update All Applicable info
4. Save
5. If you need to migrate your Xbox profile (slightly different, basically your live subscription info), then simply login and follow the process [here](https://account.xbox.com/AccountMigration)

Console Region Settings:

1. Press the Xbox button the face of your controller
2. Go to Profile & system > Settings > System > Language & location.
3. Select your desired country/location, update language options as well if you desire.
4. Restart the Console(it should prompt).

That's all you need to do.

**Note:** You can only change region/locale once every three months, your account is in good standing, you are not a minor in the "new" or current region, your billing info is correct(see steps in microsoft account), and you don't have a balance due in the previous region.